# Sphinx docs constant substitution

Tags: python, python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext, cross-reference

I use Sphinx to generate documentation for my Python project. I need to describe some default values in docs. But I don't want to copy-paste the values from code to docstring because they can easily diverge later. So the question is: **Is it possible to substitute a reference to constant with it's value?**

I'm talking about something like this (I've made up the `:py:const_value:` directive):

```
DEFAULT = 123

class Foo:
   """Default value for something is :py:const_value:`DEFAULT`."""
```

And I would like to get docs like this:

> Default value for something is 123.

I tried searching but I'm afraid there is no such function in Sphinx or "constant substitution" is not the right term.

If it's impossible to do with Sphinx, is there another *way to avoid such duplication*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the sphinx documentation ([reStructuredText Primer](http://sphinx-doc.org/rest.html)), the closest you can get appears to be to use substitutions, which are created using the `replace::` markup. For example:

```
.. |PI| replace:: 3.1415

The value of PI is |PI|.
```

which should generate

```
The value of PI is 3.14159.
```

A possibly alternative is the python domain directive `:py:const:`, which inserts a link to the definition of the value, rather than substituting the actual value.

Comment: The first option seems useless in my case, because you still have to write the literal twice - in substitution and in constant initialization. The second one is better. Link isn't as good as the actual value but at least it allows to avoid the duplication. Thanks!